# How should I provide a replacement for a package in yum?

Tags: centos, centos6, yum, rpm, specfile

I'm writing a spec file to replace a yum package with one from our own repository. The new package will be a drop-in replacement for the original.

I thought the best way to do it would be to give the spec file an identical `Conflicts` and `Provides` like one might do with a typical Arch Linux package:

```
Name:       vncsnapshot-png

Provides:   vncsnapshot
Conflicts:  vncsnapshot
```

This seemed to work, and the package can be installed/downgraded/upgraded with no issue. However, reinstallations fail:

```
Loaded plugins: security
Setting up Reinstall Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vncsnapshot-png.x86_64 0:1.3-1.el6 will be reinstalled
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

===============================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                    Arch                              Version                                 Repository                          Size
===============================================================================================================================================================
Reinstalling:
 vncsnapshot-png                            x86_64                            1.3-1.el6                               sv.repo                             35 k

Transaction Summary
===============================================================================================================================================================
Reinstall     1 Package(s)

Total download size: 35 k
Installed size: 72 k
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
vncsnapshot-png-1.3-1.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                    |  35 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
ERROR with rpm_check_debug vs depsolve:
vncsnapshot conflicts with vncsnapshot-png-1.3-1.el6.x86_64
vncsnapshot conflicts with vncsnapshot-png-1.3-1.el6.x86_64
** Found 1 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
vncsnapshot-png-1.3-1.el6.x86_64 has installed conflicts vncsnapshot: vncsnapshot-png-1.3-1.el6.x86_64
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx-2016-02-18-12-18dAjmpb.yumtx
```

Is there a way to mark the package as conflicting with the original (i.e. can't be installed at the same time) while providing the original (i.e. a drop-in replacement), without running into this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RPM language, conflicts also works against virtual provides, so your package is conflicting with itself.  To fix this, you need to qualify your `Provides` and `Conflicts` with the version macro.

```
Provides:   vncsnapshot = %{version}
Conflicts:  vncsnapshot < %{version}
```

I do this regularly for the [IUS project](https://ius.io).  You can see more examples by looking through some of our spec files.

- https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/git2u/blob/2.7.1-1.ius/SPECS/git2u.spec#L108-L110
- https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/php56u-pecl-imagick/blob/3.3.0-2.ius/SPECS/php56u-pecl-imagick.spec#L44-L45
- https://github.com/iuscommunity-pkg/redis30u/blob/3.0.7-1.ius/SPECS/redis30u.spec#L86-L89